# FileNotFoundException when use spring FileSystemResourceLoader on linux

Tags: java, linux, spring

My program structure is below:

- testProject

  - src/main/java
  - src/main/resources
  - src/test/java

    - Test.java
  - src/test/resources

    - schema/test

      - sample.xsd

The code snippet of Test.java:

```
public void test(){
    URL url = Test.class.getResource("/schema/test/sample.xsd");
    String file = url.getFile();
    Resource resource = new FileSystemResourceLoader().getResource(file);
    InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
}
```

It works well on Windows, but when I deploy it to linux, it throws FileNotFoundException exception when call resource.getInputStream, and the message is：

> opt/apps/ms/test/target/test-classes/schema/test/sample.xsd (No such
>   file or directory)

I don't know why the slash head is missing. The way to get the file isn't correct? And there are other way?

Comment: When you "deploy" to Linux? You mean as a .jar file? Because jar file entries are *not* files on the file system, so your code won't work. Since you seem to be interested in an `InputStream`, why don't use just call [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)? That will always work.

Comment: Andreas, not a jar file. I use Jekins to build the project, and run "mvn install" command, the exception occurs at Maven Test Phase,  The Test.java is a Unit Test class which uses Junit.

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream()`. That should still fix it, because what you're doing is wrong. Or, if you want/need to use a Spring `Resource`, use `Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/schema/test/sample.xsd", Test.class)`.

Comment: Andreas, The problem has been solved, thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry as I'm not an expert, but perhaps the `URL` mandates you to use `file:///opt/apps/ms/.../sample.xsd` with the proper url format?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResourceAsStream()`. That should still fix it, because what you're doing is wrong. Or, if you want/need to use a Spring `Resource`, use `Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/schema/test/sample.xsd", Test.class)`.
                    – Andreas

Andreas, The problem has been solved, thank you very much. – Rocky Hu